# How can I load an exported Tileset (image collection) from Tiled in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework, tiled

I want to load an image collection tileset into my phaser game. I know that with tilesets that are just one image you can just load that image into phaser, but what about an image collection? In Tiled I saw the options to export that tileset as either .tsx or .json, but I don't know if that helps in my case. The reason I need this is because I have some objects that are too big to be used as tiles. I can load them into Tiled and place them like I want to, but obviously they don't show up in my game, unless I can import that tileset into phaser. Does anyone know how to do that, or maybe you know a better option than using an image collection?

Comment: It doesn't exporting as `PNG` but it can export as `JSON`

Comment: Since this is **not supported out-of-the-box** by the phaser framework, can you give some more details? how big are the files _(dimesions and KB)_, that can't beloaded? How many files? On what type of layer are you using these images on (Tiles, Object, Images)? How many layer does the map have about?

Comment: btw.: did you try posting your question in the [phaser discourse](https://phaser.discourse.group/) or in the discord channel

Comment: @Sudhan does my answer, solve your issue? Or due you need some more info?

Answer (score 2):

Well after some tests, and updating my Tiled version to 1.9.2, it seems there is an pretty simple way.

1. As long as the tileset collection is marked as **"Embeded in map"**
   [image]
   *(I could have sworn, this checkbox was hidden/deactivated, when selecting "Collection of Images", in my early Tiled version)*
2. Export the map as json
3. Load map and tile-images

   ```
   preload() { 
     this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', 'export.tmj');
     this.load.image('tile01', 'tile01.png');
     this.load.image('tile02', 'tile02.png');
     ...
   }
   ```
4. create Phaser `TileSets`, just use the filename from the json as the tilsetName *(this is the **"tricky"** part, atleast for me)*

   ```
   create() {
     var map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map' });
     var img1 = map.addTilesetImage( 'tile01.png', 'tile01');
     var img2 = map.addTilesetImage( 'tile02.png', 'tile02');
     ...

     // create the layer with all tilesets
     map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1', [img1, img2, ...]);
     ... 
   }
   ```

This should work, atleast with a "Collection of images", with images that have a size of 8x8 pixel *(since I don't know the needed/intended Images size, I didn't want to waste time testing various images-sizes needlessly)*.

**Here a small demo:**
*(due to CORS-issues the map data is inserted as jsonObject and the textures are generate and not loaded)*

```js
const mapJsonExport = {"compressionlevel":-1,"height":10,"infinite":false,"layers":[{"compression":"","data":"AQAAAAEAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAACAAAAAgAAAAIAAAACAAAAAgAAAAIAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAIAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAACAAAAAQAAAAEAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABAAAAAgAAAAIAAAABAAAAAgAAAAIAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAACAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAIAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAACAAAAAQAAAAEAAAACAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAACAAAAAQAAAAIAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABAAAAAgAAAAEAAAACAAAAAgAAAAIAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABAAAAAgAAAAIAAAACAAAAAgAAAAEAAAACAAAAAQAAAA==","encoding":"base64","height":10,"id":1,"name":"Tile Layer 1","opacity":1,"type":"tilelayer","visible":true,"width":10,"x":0,"y":0}],"nextlayerid":2,"nextobjectid":1,"orientation":"orthogonal","renderorder":"right-down","tiledversion":"1.9.2","tileheight":8,"tilesets":[{"columns":0,"firstgid":1,"grid":{"height":1,"orientation":"orthogonal","width":1},"margin":0,"name":"tiles","spacing":0,"tilecount":2,"tileheight":8,"tiles":[{"id":0,"image":"tile01.png","imageheight":8,"imagewidth":8},{"id":1,"image":"tile02.png","imageheight":8,"imagewidth":8}],"tilewidth":8}],"tilewidth":8,"type":"map","version":"1.9","width":10};

var config = {
    width: 8 * 10,
    height: 8 * 10,
    zoom: 2.2,
    scene: { preload, create }
}; 

function preload() {
    // loading inline JSON due to CORS-issues with the code Snippets
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', mapJsonExport);    
    
    // generating texture instead of loading them due to CORS-issues with the code Snippets
    let graphics = this.make.graphics({add: false});
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture('tile01', 8, 8);
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0x000000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture('tile02', 8, 8);
}

function create () {
    
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map' });
    let img1 = map.addTilesetImage( 'tile01.png', 'tile01');
    let img2 = map.addTilesetImage( 'tile02.png', 'tile02');

    map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1', [img1, img2], 0, 0);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```