# Tiled Image Collection in Phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework, tiled, phaserjs, jstilemap

I was trying to import my tilemap with normal tilesets and its fine. Now I wanted to import my second tile layer, which is an Image Collection and I dont know how.
Does Phaser have a built-in method for handling image collections directly?
Because I can’t find any solutions.

My expectation was to be able to display my Image Collection from Tiled in my game.

Comment: Doesn't this answer answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/74226604/1679286 , or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah i saw that post too, but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but can you give some more context, what exactly is the issue? It's not clear what your issue is. (can you share some short demo code or so aka [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))